# How to refactor Synchronous code with future method

Tags: future, asynchronous, method

I have a `future method` that is called in trigger to create some records, and after that i use the records created in the `future method` to associate them with other entity.

Since `future methods` are asynchronous, when the code comes to the part of association, the record of `future method` are not created yet, and i got an error.

I can't move the association code to the future method because it's used in other classes, and i can't remove the `@future` annotation because it's used to avoid `Mixed DML Operation error`.

How can i solve this problem to assure that the association is executed when the future method has finished?

This is sample code of what i'm trying to do:

```java
public class MyTriggerHandler {
    // Some logic
    ...

    // Call of future Method
    MyUtilClass.callFutureMethod();

    // some logic
    ...

    // Query records created in Future Method
    List<MyObject__c> myList = new List<MyObject__c>([select Id,... from MyObject__c where ...]);   // I have the error in this line

    // Asociate object in my list with Other entity
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no choice here but to move the "association code" to a method that you call from the end of the future method and the other classes:

```
public class MyUtilClass {

    @future
    public static void callFutureMethod() {
        ...
        associationCode(...);
    }

    // Call this from the other classes
    public static void associationCode(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Asynchronous Apex usually runs quite quickly but [can be delayed for minutes or hours](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Asynchronous_Processing_in_Force_com) and having a way to wait for it to complete would pretty much undermine its purpose of allowing transactions to complete in a short amount of time.

Comment: Presumably, there would be some state to pass to `assocationCode`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Added `...` to represent that.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason to use future methods instead of queueable is when your functionality is sometimes executed synchronously, and sometimes asynchronously. It’s much easier to refactor a method in this manner than converting to a queueable class. This is handy when you discover that part of your existing code needs to be moved to async execution. You can simply create a similar future method that wraps your synchronous method like so:

@future
static void myFutureMethod(List params) {
    // call synchronous method
    mySyncMethod(params);
}